# Laravel get entry from mySql database where timestamp is not older than one day

Tags: mysql, laravel, get, timestamp, where-clause

In laravel project I have mysql table 'users' in which is timestamp column named last_visit. I want to get all users, which last_visit is not older than one day.How to perform that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) and [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/)  to archive what you want:

```
DB::table('users')->where('last_visit', '>', Carbon::today()->subDay(1));
```

or

```
Usee::where('last_visit', '>', Carbon::today()->subDay(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

`$user_last_visit = User::whereRaw('last_visit > (NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY)');`

**hope to help you**